# Deriving the projection matrix, that projects onto a vector in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra

When finding a projection matrix that projects any verctor $b$ in a two dimensional space on some vector $a$, we proceed to find P as follows. The required projected vector $p$ is some multiple of $a$ so call it: $p=ax$. We know that the perpendicular line going from the "end point" of vector $b$ to $a$ should be perpendicular to $a$, so that dot product of $a$ and that line is $0$. So we have:

$$a^T(b-ax)=0$$

From which we obtain:

$$x=\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$$

We also know that:

$$Pb=p=ax$$

$$Pb = a\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$$

So when we compare both sides we see that:

$$(P)(b)=\frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}(b)$$
so

$$P=\frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}$$

My question is the fllowing, since $x$ is a real value, we can also write (which is actually more natural): $p=xa$, so that constant is before the vector. But now we would have:

$$Pb=\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}a$$

Are we allowed to move $b$ out here like so:

$$Pb = \frac{a^Ta}{a^Ta}b$$

I assume not, because the result is not correct. How does one arrive at correct $P$ in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}a = a\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$$ because (real) scalars commute with vectors.  But you CANNOT pull the $b$ out of the first one.  So if you started from there the easiest thing to do would be to commute the scalar $\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}$ (or just the numerator) and the vector $a$ and then proceed using associativity as you did in the question:

$$\begin{align}\frac{a^Tb}{a^Ta}a &= \left(\frac{1}{a^Ta}\right)(a^Tb)a \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{a^Ta}\right)a(a^Tb) \\ &= \left(\frac{1}{a^Ta}\right)(aa^T)b \\ &= \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}b\end{align}$$